# I would like to add my outlook account from work to my laptop

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

When I attempt to add my work email, it asks for a server address and a domain. Where would I get this information?

Comment: You should be able to open up the options on your work computer and get most of them from there.  That means server, ports, etc. Some companies, however, disallow this - so I would check to be sure that is OK to do (since they tend to have fairly good security reasons as to why).

Answer (score 1):

Talk to the IT department at your workplace. Without knowing more about the email set up that they've deployed, I can't give more details. They may be able to give you the server address(es) to use, along with any other information, or they may disallow you from using your work email on a personal computer.

There can be many different ways of setting up a corporate email server, and there can be many different email clients to use with said server, so you'll need to talk to your organization's IT department to get specifics.